# PC won't sleep properly - what's likely the cause?

Tags: power-supply, sleep

My desktop PC suddenly won't sleep properly.

When I put Windows 10 to sleep manually, it appears normal, but when I push the power button to wake it up, it actually reboots as if the PC was shut down accidentally.

It was still working in the morning, and suddenly it won't work from this afternoon, without any change of BIOS firmware or Windows update whatsoever.

I checked the BIOS setting, Windows setting, even restored to previous saved state, none worked.  Used Powercfg /a to check, and it reports S3 is available.

It could still hibernate, although now I found that I couldn't reboot the PC immediately after it's off, I had to wait for about 2 minutes.  Otherwise, there is no response when I push the power button.

What is likely the cause?  if it's hardware, would it be that the PSU is failing?

Answer (score 0):

Reset your power plan.

Go to Start, Settings, Power and Sleep.

Choose Additional Power Settings.

Now in the Control Panel window that comes up, select Change Plan Settings.

Choose Advance Power Settings.

Reset your power plan to default.

Restart, update your Power Driver from the Manufacturer's Driver Support Site.

It may also be necessary to update the BIOS (UEFI) on your machine, again from the Manufacturer's Driver Support site.

Summary: Reset Power Plan to Default, Update Power Driver, Update BIOS.

Final restart after all this, set up Suspend, and test.

Follow up.  You said:

> Ok. Booted the PC with Ubuntu USB and then tried to "suspend" it. Same
> result. The did not sleep but go straight to shut down

So suspend does not work with either operating system and you have updated BIOS and Power Management drivers (latter may apply to Windows), and so now you need to consider hardware issues with the power, charging circuit and battery.

[image: Power Settings]

Comment: Thanks for your reply and illustrations, appreciated it.  I've tried this multiple times, but it's still the same.  I've even tried different BIOS version, disabling/enabling fast start-up / hiberate, etc.

Comment: You said "Very Recent" so resetting things should help. It also may be worth while to run DISM and SFC.  .... (1) Open cmd.exe with Run as Administrator.
(2) DISM.exe /Online /Cleanup-image /StartComponentCleanup
(3) DISM.exe /Online /Cleanup-Image /Restorehealth
(4) SFC /SCANNOW
(5) Restart when all the above is complete and test.

Comment: Thanks.  I still suspect it may not be related to Windows, as it reports correctly that S3 is supported and from event logs it did trigger sleep (not shut down).  I'm gonna to try booting up using Ubuntu and see if could sleep properly from it.  Will report back.

Comment: Ok.  Booted the PC with Ubuntu USB and then tried to "suspend" it.  Same result.  The did not sleep but go straight to shut down.  And then I could not reboot it immediately but have to wait for about 2 mins.  One thing I noted is that there was a short loud noise coming out of the speaker when the PC shuts down.  It's the same whether I tried to sleep from Windows or Ubuntu.

Comment: You now may need to consider hardware issues with power, charging circuit and battery.

Comment: Thanks.  Mine is a desktop, so I'll try replacing the PSU first.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, after replacing the PSU with a new one, sleep is working again.